# Can more than one person have the same devil fruit power?

Tags: one-piece

How come in the island Amazon Lily, the snake princess's sisters have the same devil fruit power?

Since only one person can have any given devil fruit power at a time, does it have to do with blood line or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have similar fruits but not the same.
[Boa Marigold](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Boa_Marigold) has the Hebi Hebi no Mi, Model: King Cobra.
[Boa Sandersonia](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Boa_Sandersonia) has the Hebi Hebi no Mi, Model: Anaconda.

> A majority of the Zoan Devil Fruits also come in different "models" that result in variations of the animal. For example, the Inu Inu (Dog) Fruit has Jackal, Dachshund, and Wolf models, the Ushi Ushi (Bull or Cow) Fruit has Bison and Giraffe models, and the Hebi Hebi (snake) has Anaconda and King Cobra models.

[Source](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Zoan#Overview)

Answer (score 0):

It has been stated multiple times more than one Devil Fruit cannot exist at the same time. The fruit grows again after the user dies. Any fruit that seems as though it already exists is just a very similar fruit but not the same one.

Comment: Hi simonee, welcome on SE! Citations and references to back up your words are always _very_ welcome. That way, readers can easily check what you say if they want instead of having to take your word for granted. Can you, for example, name a chapter or episode number in which this gets explicitly said?